# Insert background image to the bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, bootloader

I have created a boot loader in Assembly which is outputting "Hello World". I want to insert a background image to this boot loader. So how can I modify this code? Thank you very much.

```
bits 16 ;
org 0x7c00 ; 

jmp main ; 



Message db "Welcome Home, booting from low-level 16-bit...", 0x0 
MessageB db "Chaturaka's own bootloader program written in x86 assembly language.", 0x0
AnyKey db "Press any key to reboot...", 0x0 

;
Println:
    lodsb ;
    or al, al
    jz complete
    mov ah, 0x0e    
    int 0x10 ;
    jmp Println ;   
complete:
    call PrintNwL

;   
PrintNwL: 
    mov al, 0   ; 
    stosb       ; 


    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, 0x0D
    int 0x10
    mov al, 0x0A 
    int 0x10
    ret

;
Reboot: 
    mov si, AnyKey
    call Println
    call GetPressedKey 

    ;

    db 0x0ea 
    dw 0x0000 
    dw 0xffff 

;
GetPressedKey:
    mov ah, 0
    int 0x16  ;
    ret 

;
main:
   cli ;

   mov ax,cs              
   mov ds,ax   
   mov es,ax               
   mov ss,ax                
   sti ;

   mov si, Message 
   call Println 

   mov si, MessageB
   call Println 

   call PrintNwL
   call PrintNwL

   call Reboot 

   times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ;
   dw 0xAA55 ;
```

Hope you will answer thsi question.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you need to perform:

- [Set a graphics mode](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) (e.g. mode 0Dh or mode 13h).
- (Optionally) Set up the palette if your image doesn't use the default palette.
- Load the image data from disk and write it to video memory, typically starting at segment 0A000h.

Comment: Loading image data from disc required filesystem support which not that popular (guess why). the image should be hard-coded in the code section (or data section)

Comment: _"[It] requires filesystem support"_. Not if the image is stored as raw sectors on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [osdev WIKI](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), for a lot of useful information regarding OS and bootloader development.
[here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode) you can find valuable information regarding screen drawing in protected mode.